# How to create custom context in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

I want to create custom context in OpenERP. Need something like polish notation in domain with '|'. Need also hierarchial like 'region_id','child_of','region_id.parent_id'. is it possible?
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can dump any data you want into the context, and it's up to the server-side code to interpret that data. The only time I've run into trouble with context was when two screens used the same key in context but put conflicting data there. Then visiting one screen would break the other screen.